# jQuery(...).val(...).xxx is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use `EggImageDropdown`, but I have problems with the script.

I embedded it in my testing site and there it works:
http://herzschloss.de/hs/test.php at "Mein Wunschbild".

Now I want to use the same script with the same linked in js-code here:
http://herzschloss.de/Liebesschloss-bestellen at "Mein Wunschbild"

But I get an error.

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).val(...).EggImageDropdown is not a function
```

This is the live generated script that didn't work:

```
function onclick(event) {
    var t = jQuery('select[id=dropdown_demo]').val('herz.png').EggImageDropdown('close').EggImageDropdown('update',{src:'hs-motive/herz.png'});t.trigger('change');
}
```

This is the code:

```
jQuery('option',element).each(function(i,el){
    dropdown.append('<img style="width:100%" onclick="var t=jQuery(\'select[id=' + selectName + ']\').val(\''+ $(el).val() + '\').EggImageDropdown(\'close\').EggImageDropdown(\'update\',{src:\''+ $(el).text() + '\'});t.trigger(\'change\');" src="' + $(el).text() + '"/>');
});
```

It would be great if you help me!

Comment: `jQuery(selector).val()` gives you the value in return unless you are setting the value.You cannot call jQuery functions after it.

Comment: @StarxI He's using it as a setter, which returns the jQuery object. It's completely valid to chain additional methods off the end of a `jQuery(...).val(something)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to embed that much code into an `onclick` attribute. Better to not do it.

To correct it, create the function directly in the loop instead of creating an attribute.

```
jQuery('option',element).each(function(i,el){
    var img = $('<img>', {style: "width:100%;", src: $(el).text()});
    img.click(function() {
        var t=jQuery('select[id=' + selectName + ']');
        t.val($(el).val()).EggImageDropdown('close')
                          .EggImageDropdown('update', {src:$(el).text()});
        t.trigger('change');
    });
    dropdown.append(img); 
});
```

---

Furthermore, looking at your linked site, it appears that the `EggImageDropdown` function doesn't exist, which means you're not successfully loading the plugin.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it don't work. I replaced the code and get now:

TypeError: t.val(...).EggImageDropdown is not a function
.EggImageDropdown('close')

Comment: @SebastianHensel: Then your plugin probably isn't loaded properly

Comment: @SebastianHensel: I typed `jQuery.fn.EggImageDropdown` into the console, and got `undefined`. So it does seem that's the issue.